# How do I query Spark JobServer and find where it stores my Jars?

Tags: spark-jobserver

I am trying to follow this documentation:

https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver#dependency-jars

**Option 2 Listed in the docs says:**

> The dependent-jar-uris can also be used in job configuration param
>   when submitting a job. On an ad-hoc context this has the same effect
>   as dependent-jar-uris context configuration param. On a persistent
>   context the jars will be loaded for the current job and then for every
>   job that will be executed on the persistent context.  curl -d ""
>   'localhost:8090/contexts/test-context?num-cpu-cores=4&memory-per-node=512m'
>   OK⏎   curl
>   'localhost:8090/jobs?appName=test&classPath=spark.jobserver.WordCountExample&context=test-context&sync=true'
>   -d '{ dependent-jar-uris = ["file:///myjars/deps01.jar", "file:///myjars/deps02.jar"], input.string = "a b c a b see" }'  The
>   jars /myjars/deps01.jar & /myjars/deps02.jar (present only on the SJS
>   node) will be loaded and made available for the Spark driver &
>   executors.

**Is "file:///myjars/" directory the SJS node's JAR directory or some custom directory?**

I have a client on a Windows box and a Spark JobServer on a Linux box.  Next, I upload a JAR to SJS node.  SJS node puts that Jar somewhere.  Then, when I call to start a Job and set the 'dependent-jar-uris', the SJS node will find my previously uploaded JAR and run the job:

**"dependent-jar-uris" set to "file:///tmp/spark-jobserver/filedao/data/simpleJobxxxxxx.jar"**

This works fine, but I had to manually go searching around the SJS node to find this location (e.g. file:///tmp/spark-jobserver/filedao/data/simpleJobxxxxxx.jar) and then add it into my future requests to start the job.

Instead, **how to I make a REST call from the client to just get the path where Spark JobServer puts my jars when I uploaded them, so that I can set the file:/// path correctly in my 'dependent-jar-uris' property dynamically?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think uploaded jars using "POST /jars" can be used in dependent-jar-uris. Since you are uploading jars, you already know the local path. Just use that.

Comment: In my case, the job execution client does not have a reference to the JARs locally on the client.  It expects them to be on the server already.   If the Spark JobServer allows for separately uploading jars via a REST api, then how are they ever referenced later, if not via the 'dependent-jar-uris' ?

Comment: POST /jars is not for uploading dependent jars. It is for uploading spark app jar. I would recommend you to copy all your dependent jars to spark job server linux box and add them to dependent-jar-uris in spark jobsever conf itself.